# SQL Server Query for getting column names of all tables as XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

In my database, I intend to get the - [TableName] as the first column and all columns of that table in a ", " (comma followed by space - delimiter) as the second column - for all tables in the DB.

```
Table A | ColumnA1, ColumnA2, ColumnA3  
Table B | ColumnB1, ColumnB2, ColumnB3
......................................
```

And retrieve it as an XML

```
<TableList>  
<TableName>TableA</TableName> <Columns> ColumnA1, ColumnA2, ColumnA3</Columns>  
<TableName>TableB</TableName> <Columns> ColumnB1, ColumnB2, ColumnB3</Columns>  
</TableList>
```

How should the SQL Query be written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the XML you ask for.

```
select T.name as TableName,
       (
         select ', '+C.name
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = T.object_id
         order by C.column_id
         for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring((./text())[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as Columns
from sys.tables as T
order by T.name
for xml path(''), root('TableList')
```

But I think this would return an XML that is easier to handle.

```
select T.name as TableName,
       (
         select ', '+C.name
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = T.object_id
         order by C.column_id
         for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring((./text())[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as Columns
from sys.tables as T
order by T.name
for xml path('Table'), root('TableList')
```

Or perhaps like this.

```
select T.name as TableName,
       (
         select C.name as ColumnName
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = T.object_id
         order by C.column_id
         for xml path(''), type
       ) as Columns
from sys.tables as T
order by T.name
for xml path('Table'), root('TableList')
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
   select isc.TABLE_NAME,stuff((
    SELECT ',' + cast(column_name as varchar(20))
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME =isc.TABLE_NAME 
     group by TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
    FOR XML PATH('') 
    ),1,1,'')  as column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc
     group by TABLE_NAME
```